# Associate dynamically generated controls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a table with dynamically generated rows that contain some form controls. Every row has a checkbox with Id value and textbox with some other data. When dealing with incoming form data in controller action I have no match between value from textbox and id value from checkbox. 
Is there a simple ,clean and efficient way to solve this problem?

I've considered adding an Id value to textbox name to match checkbox value with textbox value but it seems to be a dirty way.

HTML code looks like this (after some modifications):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> <input type="text" name="Users[0].Date"/> </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="Users[0].Id"/> <td>
</tr>
```

Is there a way to bind this data to some clean model and have a match between data in table row?

The controller action :

```
public ActionResult Edit(EditViewModel model)
{
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
public class EditViewModel{
    ICollection<UserItem> Users{ get; set; }
}

public class UserItem{
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
    public int Id{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your controller code?

Comment: You could have a model with an ICollection that represents the rows. Then for each row, set the name of your HTML input to something like `name="CollectionProperty[i].Date"` where CollectionProperty is the collection on your model class, i is the row index, and Date is the property you are binding to. When you POST, the ModelBinder should automatically bind the input to your collection property for you.

Comment: I have added a collection to model but after binding it is null. What type should it have? Another model?

Comment: without seeing the model we're not going to be able to help you with that. Probably would also help to see the controller code and maybe the form tags.

Comment: I have added some models code

Comment: @drv, your collection property, `ICollection<UserItem> Users{ get; set; }` needs to be public.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem!